# How can i remove duplicates from a union select on a subset of the selected tables

Tags: mysql, database, union

I am trying to remove duplicate title rows while sorting by an alias

```
SELECT title,description,
                                (CASE WHEN title LIKE '%$searchterm%' then 10 else 0 END)+ 
                                (CASE WHEN keywords LIKE '%$searchterm%' then 5 else 0 END)+
                                (CASE WHEN description LIKE '%$searchterm%' then 3 else 0 END) 
                                AS priority
                                FROM searchengine 
                                WHERE
                                internalpage
                                HAVING priority > 0

for ($i=0;$i<=$spaces;$i++){
    $qrySearch .= "UNION SELECT title,description,
                                (CASE WHEN title LIKE '%$str_arr[$i]%' then 2 else 0 END)+ 
                                (CASE WHEN keywords LIKE '%$str_arr[$i]%' then 1 else 0 END)+
                                (CASE WHEN description LIKE '%$str_arr[$i]%' then 0.5 else 0 END) 
                                AS priority
                                FROM searchengine 
                                WHERE
                                internalpage
                                HAVING priority > 0
    $qrySearch .=   ORDER BY priority DESC
```

The results are sorted correctly by highest priority but there are rows in which the titles are the same. I want remove those rows within the SQL i am aware I easily remove them after

Comment: Union don't return duplicated  .. rows .. so if you want don't show some column content for a parte of the column you must work on the result of the query server side  with procedural code .. (not sql)

Comment: The "duplicated" rows have the same title but different priority. Which of them exactly do you want to remove? I think you should better just sum up the priorities for the same title.

Comment: I want to remove the rows with duplicated titles with the lowest priority

Comment: I tried sum() and group by title neither of which worked

Comment: "I tried sum() and group by title" - But it should: `SELECT title,description, SUM(priority) FROM (<original query>) sub GROUP BY title,description ORDER BY SUM(priority)  DESC`. And maybe use `UNION ALL` so you don't remove duplicated priorities in the SUM.

Comment: BTW: I would just fetch all rows and calculate the priority in application langiage.

Comment: Seems i will have to use this method